# How the following conditional statement works

Tags: python, list, byte

can someone explain me how this code works ? I really appreciated

```
def inc_bytes(a):
    """ Returns a new byte array with the value increment by 1 """
    out = list(a)
    for i in reversed(range(len(out))):
        if out[i] == 0xff:
            out[i] = 0
        else:
            out[i] += 1 
            break
    return bytes(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the end of a bytes array (e.g., `b'\x01\x02\x03\xff'`), it takes each byte and checks if this is 255 (0xff), in which case it changes the byte to 0 and continues with the previous byte. If it encounters a non 0xff byte, it increases its value from 1 and stops.

```
inc_bytes(b'\x01\x02\x03\xff\xff')
# b'\x01\x02\x04\x00\x00'
```

In decimal, this changes `[1, 2, 3, 255, 255]` into `[1, 2, 4, 0, 0]`, some kind of base 255 numbering limited by the number of bytes (resets to all 0 after all 255).

Comment: thank you , but can you tell me what its purpose can be ?

Comment: Without context, no.

Comment: Well you know , I am using this script in AES cryptosystem , and in CTR mode , we need an initial value as bytes type , and this function gets the initial value as an input , our IV is 16 bytes .